# Dynamically add locally stored images to list view

Tags: react-native

I would like to render locally stored images into a ListView. It seems I cannot use source={require( category.image )} due to the way the app is packaged. Using source={{uri: category.image}} does not crash my app but also doesn't load the image. Here is my React Native class:

```
var Categories = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
{'name':'Test', 'image':'./images/categories/test.jpg'},
      ]),
    };
  },

  renderCategory: function(category) {

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={{uri: category.image}}>

          <View style={styles.backdropView}>
            <Text style={styles.headline}>
              {category.name}
            </Text>
          </View>

        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  },

  render: function() {

    return (

      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderCategory} />
    );
  },
});
```

How can I add the images to the page without hard coding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Native packager will preprocess your code and look for `require` statements that points to images and bundle those with your app. Since this is done at compile time and not run time you cannot dynamically require them.

If you must do that, then I'd suggest using remote images or adding them to `Images.xcassets` and using `{uri: 'asset_name'}` instead. Another approach would be to create an array or object at startup with a bunch of `require`'s and then use that content dynamically.

Comment: I was able to add require to the image property of each object: dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {'name':'test', 'image':require('./images/categories/test.jpg')},

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to host them remotely and call them into cache and use one of the cacheing libraries to handle the assets.

https://github.com/llanox/react-native-assets

This should help you with this process.  You may be able to find creative ways to do this in other ways using the same concepts.

Your other option as suggested in another answer is to use your Images.xcassets