# How to parse json in react-native for android app?

Tags: android, json, listview, react-native

I've this data in json format

```
const infoData = [
    { "code": "AL", "label": "Alabama", "tiles": [{'description': 'The University Of Alabama', 'img': '/AL/AL_1.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Campus Map', 'img': '/AL/AL_2.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Seal of Alabama', 'img': '/AL/AL_3.png'}, {'description': 'University of Alabama - System', 'img': '/AL/AL_4.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Alabama', 'img': '/AL/AL_5.jpg'}, {'description': 'National Water Center', 'img': '/AL/AL_6.jpeg'}, {'description': 'President\'s Mansion', 'img': '/AL/AL_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Bryant - Denny Stadium', 'img': '/AL/AL_8.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Governer - Elect', 'img': '/AL/AL_9.png'}, {'description': 'Motto Of Alabama', 'img': '/AL/AL_10.jpg'}] },
    { "code": "AK", "label": "Alaska", "tiles": [{'description': 'Alaska Map', 'img': '/AK/AK_1.png'}, {'description': 'Mediterranean Cruises', 'img': '/AK/AK_2.jpg'}, {'description': 'Alaska Cruises', 'img': '/AK/AK_3.jpg'}, {'description': 'Department of Natural Resources', 'img': '/AK/AK_4.jpg'}, {'description': 'Coastal Rainforest Center', 'img': '/AK/AK_5.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Alaska\'s Polar Bears', 'img': '/AK/AK_6.jpg'}, {'description': 'Alaska State Fair', 'img': '/AK/AK_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Governors of Alaska', 'img': '/AK/AK_8.png'}, {'description': 'Alaska Railroad', 'img': '/AK/AK_9.jpg'}, {'description': 'University of Alaska', 'img': '/AK/AK_10.jpeg'}] },
    { "code": "AS", "label": "American Samoa", "tiles": [{'description': 'National Park', 'img': '/AS/AS_1.jpg'}, {'description': 'Ofu Beach', 'img': '/AS/AS_2.jpg'}, {'description': 'Tradewinds Hotel', 'img': '/AS/AS_3.jpg'}, {'description': 'American Samoa Territory', 'img': '/AS/AS_4.jpg'}, {'description': 'American Samoa Map', 'img': '/AS/AS_5.jpeg'}, {'description': 'American Samoa - Alchetron', 'img': '/AS/AS_6.jpg'}, {'description': 'Surfing', 'img': '/AS/AS_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Power Authority', 'img': '/AS/AS_8.jpg'}, {'description': 'EPA Office', 'img': '/AS/AS_9.jpg'}, {'description': 'Pago Pago Hotel', 'img': '/AS/AS_10.jpeg'}] },
    { "code": "AZ", "label": "Arizona", "tiles": [{'description': 'Arizona - Logo', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_1.png'}, {'description': 'Arizona Sunsets', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_2.jpg'}, {'description': 'Arizona Map', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_3.jpg'}, {'description': 'The University Of Arizona', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_4.png'}, {'description': 'Arizona Geology', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_5.jpg'}, {'description': 'USS Arizona Memorial', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_6.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Luxury Phoenix Hotels', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Arizona Inn (Tucson)', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_8.jpg'}, {'description': 'Global Village', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_9.jpg'}, {'description': 'Arizona Farm Bureau', 'img': '/AZ/AZ_10.jpeg'}] },
    { "code": "AR", "label": "Arkansas", "tiles": [{'description': 'University of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_1.jpg'}, {'description': 'Map of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_2.jpg'}, {'description': 'Flag of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_3.png'}, {'description': 'Peabody Hall', 'img': '/AR/AR_4.jpeg'}, {'description': 'AM³ Lab', 'img': '/AR/AR_5.jpg'}, {'description': 'State of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_6.jpg'}, {'description': 'IEEE of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Western District of Arkansas', 'img': '/AR/AR_8.jpg'}, {'description': 'Shaping the University', 'img': '/AR/AR_9.jpg'}, {'description': 'Student Apartments', 'img': '/AR/AR_10.jpeg'}] },
    { "code": "CA", "label": "California", "tiles": [{'description': 'California Map', 'img': '/CA/CA_1.png'}, {'description': 'Resources in California', 'img': '/CA/CA_2.jpg'}, {'description': 'Beach Getaways', 'img': '/CA/CA_3.jpeg'}, {'description': 'California Gold Rush', 'img': '/CA/CA_4.jpeg'}, {'description': 'Student Aid Commission', 'img': '/CA/CA_5.png'}, {'description': 'Senators', 'img': '/CA/CA_6.jpg'}, {'description': 'Disney California Adventure Park', 'img': '/CA/CA_7.jpg'}, {'description': 'Disney California Adventure Park', 'img': '/CA/CA_8.jpg'}, {'description': 'Judicial Branch', 'img': '/CA/CA_9.png'}, {'description': 'California Wines', 'img': '/CA/CA_10.jpeg'}] },
];
```

I need to display all the description and image in a ListView in android, I'm using the below code using which I can display the labels in a ListView,

```
renderListItem(listItem) {
return (
    <View>
      <Text>{listItem.label}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

}

but how should I parse this data to show the description and images(which are in a folder named img) in ListView?

Comment: @Rotwang that's the JSX syntax used in React Native

Comment: @Rahul you need to `require` images before it can be used. This comment might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092349/dynamically-add-locally-stored-images-to-list-view#comment56008032_34094787

Answer (score 0):

Just parse through the array of tiles and add the `<Image/>` component bound to the value. **Note**: you'll need to provide the height and width for the images since they'll be required in real time.

Assuming this folder structure..

```
/app
  -index.ios.js
/img
  /AL
    -AL_1.jpg
```

The `/AL/AL_1.jpg` is coming in the API call.. so you'll need to prepend the require statement to match where the files are. This is assuming the files are in the project directly, not on the CameralRoll.. there's a entirely different API to go there.

**index.ios.js**

```
renderListItem(listItem) {
  let tiles = listItem.tiles.map(tile => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{tile.description}</Text>
        <Image source={require(`../img/${tile.img}`)} style={{heigh: 50, width: 50}}/> 
      </View>
    )
  })
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{listItem.label}</Text>
      {tiles}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: I don't think `uri` would work. Images are locally stored.

Comment: images are not loading, how to load the images which are stored in local directory and their path given in the json?

Comment: The path in the require needs to be relative to where the file is located. Updating answer.

Comment: I tried the updated code but it is not working, it shows Requiring unknown module "./img./${tile.img}" message in a red screen on the android phone.

Comment: I used string literals... you have to use the ticks `\``. You could also do `require('../img/' + tile.img)`

Comment: Also not sure why you added a period after the img folder.